How to exclude "branch not taken" reporting for specific lines in gcovr?
I am working on a C++ project compiled with g++ --coverage so that unit testing generates coverage metrics, which are converted to html reports by gcovr.
The branch coverage information is misleading, because a large number of the "branch not taken" results are for code implicitly generated by the compiler. For example:
class Derived : public AbstractBase {
public:
    Derived(SharedObjectPtr sharedObjectPtr, const OtherParameters& otherParameters)
        : AbstractBase(sharedObjectPtr, otherParameters) {}; // <-- Branch 3 not taken
};

and:
class SpecialList {
private:
    unsigned length;
public:
    SpecialList() : length(0) {};
    ~SpecialList() {}; // <-- Branch 1 not taken
};

It is not reasonable to generate test code to exercise these implicit branches. We want to exclude these implicit "branch-not-taken" results, so that the coverage report accurately reflects branch coverage of our source code.
The gcovr documentation describes exclude-branches-by-pattern, albeit without any examples. I added this line to the gcovr.cfg file:
exclude-branches-by-pattern = ~SpecialList

But the same "branch not taken" issue is still reported. For reference, we're using g++ 13.2.0 and gcovr 7.0.
How can we exclude specific lines from being reported with "branch not taken"?
UPDATE: Noting this answer, I added --exclude-throw-branches to the gcovr command line, but the same "branch not taken" issues are still reported.

It's very probable that a bug like this exists in gcovr, especially as there are next to no docs/tests for this feature. But I couldn't reproduce your problem directly. Would you mind creating a reproducible example with a shell script like the following, and attach the output that shows uncovered branches on the destructor's line? https://gist.github.com/latk/edde79864853c3fa49b2b3bb74296e58

In the gist: https://gist.github.com/LeeJenkins/2c2b178b045fd5ee5b554d1488258439 , the invocation of the AbstractBase does not have untaken branches, but three other lines do. The gcovr results are the same regardless of the usage of --exclude-branches-by-pattern.

Perfect, can reproduce. Turns out that the exclude-lines-by-pattern mechanism anchors the regex at the start of each line (regex.match() call here, instead of regex.search()). So you need to add a .* to skip unwanted content on the line. For example, the config file in your post might use .*~SpecialList. I can't be bothered to write a full answer about this, but you may consider writing an answer here and/or submitting a documentation bug report to the gcovr project.

BTW, gcovr source code markup solved the reporting issue. Any line with the string  GCOVR_EXCL_BR_LINE is excluded from "branch not taken" reporting. The solution is far from ideal.

lcov is a different tool - but has a lot of features for this sort of exclusion and filtering.

@HenryCox Thanks for the reply. I have used lcov before, but It did not report branch coverage. Perhaps I missed it. Is there an option to enable branch coverage?
